# Mongoose Follower and Following query optimization

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document in mongo for maintaining following and followers for my social app using this one schema.I have close to 3000 records in this document.

```
var FollowSchema = new Schema({
                uid : {
                    type: Schema.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'User'
                },
                fid : {
                    type: Schema.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'User'
                }
            });
```

Currently I am fetching all the users who are followers of the logged in users like the below :

```
       Follow.find({ fid : req.user._id})
      .populate('fid' , {name,_id}).lean().exec(function(err,               details) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json(err);
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json(details);
                }
            });
```

Without using inner query or Asycn , is it possible to find if the logged-in user is mutually "following" the followers ?

I looked at MapReduce and aggregation but not sure if that would work.

Any sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do the mongoose mapping of this in my head, but this is one way to do it in mongodb (4711 here being your uid, note that it's mentioned 3 times in the query)

```
db.follow.aggregate(
 {$match: {$or: [{uid:4711},{fid:4711}]}},    // Find all entries regarding user.
 {$project:                                   // Project user to uid,
  {z:                                         // followed/follower to fid and
   {$cond:[                                   // the type to followed/followed.
    {$eq:["$uid",4711]},
     {fid:"$fid", following:{$literal:1}},
     {fid:"$uid", followed:{$literal:1}}]
   }
  }
 },
 {$group:{_id:"$z.fid",                       // Group by fid to get the total
          following:{$sum:"$z.following"},    // type of the other user 
          followed:{$sum:"$z.followed"}}
 }
)

# You're followed by 3
# { "_id" : 3, "following" : 0, "followed" : 1 }
# You're following 4 and he/she is following you back
# { "_id" : 4, "following" : 1, "followed" : 1 }
# You're follwing 2
# { "_id" : 2, "following" : 1, "followed" : 0 }
```